# Undefined index: REQUEST_URI and HTTP_HOST

Tags: php

How can I get rid of this errors.

```
Line 8 : define('CURRENT_PAGE', basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
Line 15: define('READ_PATH', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/read.php?id=');
```

errors:

```
Undefined index: REQUEST_URI in ......... on line 8
Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in ....... on line 15
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: Welcome to SO! This site is really for specific questions, it is not a debgging tool. Please check for other similar questions (like the ones listed above) before asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use CLI then u can check them for their existence but in the browser, HTTP_HOST will be available any time.

```
 if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
    define('CURRENT_PAGE', basename($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));
 }

 if (!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
     define('CURRENT_PAGE', basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
 }
```